# AYUDA No puedo enviar PDF en mail desde Base de Datos

Tags: php, mysql

tenía un formulario que pedía correo y enviaba a una función que respondía con información. Ahora le agregué un campo Hidden en el formulario para enviar por POST la ruta del archivo, pero al enviar me da error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Content' (T_STRING) in /home/idecap/public_html/php/mail.php on line 10

He buscado pero no doy con el error, les comparto el código.

`Función mail.php`

```html
<?php

$para = $_POST['EMAIL'];
$nombre = $_POST['id'];
$copia = "consultas@idecap.org";
$descarga = "www.idecap.org/administrar/upload/$nombre";
$asunto = "DESCUENTO ESPECIAL - APROVECHA AHORA MISMO";

$mensaje = "<html lang ='es'>"
          . "<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">"
          . "<title>Descarga el Temario con un descuento Especial</title>"
          . ""
          . "</head>"
          . "<body>"
          . "Gracias por capacitarte con IDECAP Educaci贸n Ejecutiva"
          . " para acceder al temario con el descuento del curso, da clic aqu&iacute;: </br>"
          . "<a href='$descarga'> Acceder</a>"
          ."</body>"
          . "</html>";

$cabeceras ='MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras.='Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$cabeceras.= 'From: IDECAP Educacion Ejecutiva <consultas@idecap.org>' ."\r\n";

mail("$para,$copia", $asunto, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
?>;
```

Y ésta es la parte del formulario:

```html
<form id="mailchimp-subscription-form1" class="newsletter-form mt-40" method="POST" action="php/mail.php">
              <label for="mce-EMAIL"></label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <input type="email" id="mce-EMAIL" data-height="45px" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Tu Email" name="EMAIL" value="">
                <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" value="<?php $row['descarga_pdf']; ?>">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-colored btn-dark btn-lg m-0" data-height="45px">Recibir</button>
                </span>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Content' (T_STRING)

significa : encontré la palabra "Content" sin esperarmelo

Cuando armas el mensaje estas usando comillas dobles dentro de comillas dobles, hay que "escapearlas" para que no se rompa la cadena (ponerlas con un \ delante)

```
$mensaje = "<html lang ='es'>"
      . "<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">"
      . "<title>Descarga el Temario con un descuento Especial</title>"
```

Quedaría así

```
$mensaje = "<html lang ='es'>"
      . "<head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=gb18030\">"
      . "<title>Descarga el Temario con un descuento Especial</title>"
```

de esa manera no se rompe la cadena del mensaje.

**Edición**

Código completo modificado (cambié algunas cosas para una prueba local)

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$para = "email@server.com";//$_POST['EMAIL'];
$nombre = "Nombre";//$_POST['id'];
$copia = "copia@server.com";//"consultas@idecap.org";
$descarga = "www.idecap.org/administrar/upload/$nombre";
$asunto = "DESCUENTO ESPECIAL - APROVECHA AHORA MISMO";

$mensaje = "<html lang ='es'>"
          . "<head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=gb18030\">"
          . "<title>Descarga el Temario con un descuento Especial</title>"
          . ""
          . "</head>"
          . "<body>"
          . "Gracias por capacitarte con IDECAP Educaci贸n Ejecutiva"
          . " para acceder al temario con el descuento del curso, da clic aqu&iacute;: </br>"
          . "<a href='$descarga'> Acceder</a>"
          ."</body>"
          . "</html>";

$cabeceras ='MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras.='Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$cabeceras.= 'From: IDECAP Educacion Ejecutiva <consultas@idecap.org>' ."\r\n";
var_dump("$para,$copia", $asunto, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
?>;
```

como verás en vez de enviar el mail, muestro los datos por pantalla con `var_dump();` y el resultado es:

```
$ ./stringtest.php
string(33) "email@server.com,copia@server.com"
string(42) "DESCUENTO ESPECIAL - APROVECHA AHORA MISMO"
string(377) "<html lang ='es'><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030"><title>Descarga el Temario con un descuento Especial</title></head><body>Gracias por capacitarte con IDECAP Educaci贸n Ejecutiva para acceder al temario con el descuento del curso, da clic aqu&iacute;: </br><a href='www.idecap.org/administrar/upload/Nombre'> Acceder</a></body></html>"
string(121) "MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
From: IDECAP Educacion Ejecutiva <consultas@idecap.org>
"
;
```

Así que si aún tienes errores debe ser diferente el texto del error y estar en otro lado.

Comment: Hice los cambios "escapear" el contenido, pero el error persiste.

Comment: mismo error? o en otra linea?

Comment: Sí, estaba bien, el problema era que lo estaba editando desde Cpanel y no guardaba la modificación. Después horas de soporte, eliminé los archivos y los subí modificados y quedo bien.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas mezclando comillas dobles y simples.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```
$mensaje = "<html lang ='es'>"
      . "<head><meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=gb18030'>"
      . "<title>Descarga el Temario con un descuento Especial</title>"
      . ""
      . "</head>"
      . "<body>"
      . "Gracias por capacitarte con IDECAP Educaci贸n Ejecutiva"
      . " para acceder al temario con el descuento del curso, da clic aqu&iacute;: </br>"
      . "<a href='$descarga'> Acceder</a>"
      ."</body>"
      . "</html>";
```

Comment: Hola, ése cambio lo hice antes de publicar. El error es el mismo, por eso no logro dar con el error.